Proof that sum of ordinals is isomorphic to sum of two well-ordered sets

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be two ordinals. Prove that $\alpha + \beta \cong sum(\alpha, \beta)$. Here, $\alpha + \beta$ is defined recursively by
$$\alpha + 0 = \alpha;\quad \alpha + (\beta + 1) = (\alpha + \beta) + 1;\quad (\alpha + \beta) = sup\{\alpha + \epsilon : \epsilon < \beta \} \text{ if $\beta$ is limit oridnal}$$
And, $$sum(\alpha, \beta) = \alpha \cup \beta$$ defined on two
disjoint linearly ordered sets(not necessarily ordinal) with the (linear)
ordering  $<$ defined by:   $$\forall a, b\in \alpha: a <_{\alpha} b$$
$$\forall a, b\in \beta: a <_{\beta} b$$ $$a \in \alpha \land b\in
\beta \Rightarrow a < b$$

Proof: Induction by $\beta$(this is the hint).
My attempt: The base case. Let $\beta = 0$. Then, $\alpha + 0 = \alpha$. Also, $sum(\alpha, 0) = \alpha$ and the defined ordering is just the ordering in $\alpha$ by definition. Hence, the isomorphism (in fact equality).
Successor case: We assume $\alpha + \beta \cong sum(\alpha, \beta)$. Then,
$$\alpha + (\beta + 1) = (\alpha + \beta) + 1 = (\alpha + \beta) + \{\alpha + \beta\}$$
$$sum(\alpha, \beta + 1) = \alpha \cup (\beta + 1) = \alpha \cup \beta \cup \{\beta\}$$
Then, consider the isomorphism $h: sum(\alpha, \beta) \leftrightarrow \alpha + \beta$. By defining $h': sum(\alpha, \beta + 1) \rightarrow \alpha + (\beta + 1)$ by
$$h'_{|sum(\alpha, \beta)} = h;\quad h(\beta) = (\alpha + \beta)$$
, we have proved
$$sum(\alpha, \beta + 1) \cong \alpha + (\beta + 1)$$
Indeed, we only need to check if function is bijective for $h(\beta)$ and order-preserving for $x \in (\alpha \cup \beta)$ and $\beta$. Firstly, it is surely surjective and the injectivity is due to
$$h(\beta) = h(x) \Rightarrow x \in (\alpha \cup \beta) \text{ is absurd}$$
since $h = h'$ in that sub-domain. So, the function is bijective. The order-preserving follows in the same manner.
The post here suggests to take $\bigcup_{\epsilon} h_{\epsilon}$ to get a map
$$\bigcup_{\epsilon < \beta} {(\alpha + \epsilon)} \leftrightarrow \bigcup_{\epsilon < \beta} sum(\alpha, \epsilon)$$
But how is "the union" well-defined? Is it similar to my proof on Transfinite recursion? It does not even make sense to write
$$\bigcup_{\epsilon < \beta} sum(\alpha, \epsilon)$$

My hint would be to use site search since this question has appeared already (in fact, every basic question about ordinal numbers or any other topic). Instead of $\alpha \cup \beta$ one should write $\alpha \sqcup \beta$ or something similar, the union is not correct.

@MartinBrandenburg Same question but specific purposes worth posting questions, right? I searched everything up, there's exactly one question related to my problem.

You can find a proof of this in "Classic Set Theory, Goldrei" Theorem 8.8. If you write out the proof with all the steps (like I have :)) it is quite long but not very complex. An illuminating summary of the proof is quite short.
We define $\alpha^\#$ as $\alpha$ x $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\alpha^{\#\#}$ as $\alpha$ x $\{\emptyset^+\}$ and $\alpha \sqcup \beta$ as $\alpha^\# \cup \beta^{\#\#}$. And define $\underline\in_\alpha^\#$ by $<x_1,y_1> \underline\in_\alpha^\# <x_2,y_2> \iff  x_1 \underline\in_\alpha x_2$ and $y_1=y_2=0$ and $\underline\in_\alpha^{\#\#}$ by $<x_1,y_1> \underline\in_\alpha^{\#\#} <x_2,y_2> \iff  x_1 \underline\in_\alpha x_2$ and $y_1=y_2=1$. I will call the order that you define above as the "usual order".
As per your hint, you use transfinite induction and induct on $\beta$. We are trying to show $\varphi(\beta)$ where $\varphi(\beta) \equiv \alpha + \beta = sum(\alpha,\beta)$ and our induction hypothesis is $\zeta \in \beta \rightarrow \varphi(\zeta)$. The case for $\beta = \emptyset$ is straight-forwards. For a successor ordinal, $\beta=\delta^+$,. define a function $g$ on $\alpha \sqcup \beta$ where $\beta=\delta^+$ by
\begin{equation}
  g: x \mapsto \left \{
  \begin{aligned}
    &f(x), && \text{if}\ x \in \alpha \sqcup \delta \\
    &\alpha + \delta, && \text{if} \ x= <\delta,1>
  \end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}
where $f$ is the isomorphism from  $<\alpha \sqcup \delta,\le>$ to $<\alpha + \delta,\underline\in_{\alpha+\delta}>$ where $\le$ is the usual order from $<\alpha^\#,\underline\in_{\alpha}^\#>$ to $<\delta^{\#\#},\underline\in_{\delta}^{\#\#}>$  which exists by our IH. Then show that $g$ is an isomorphism between  $<\alpha \sqcup \beta,\le_1>$ and $<\alpha + \beta,\underline\in_{\alpha+\beta}>$ where $\le_1$ is the usual order from $<\alpha^\#,\underline\in_{\alpha}^\#>$ to $<\delta^{\#\#},\underline\in_{\beta}^{\#\#}>$. I think this is the same argument you have used for the successor case.
And for the limit case, define $h_\eta$ on $\alpha \sqcup \eta$ by:
\begin{equation}
  h_\eta: x \mapsto \left \{
  \begin{aligned}
    &\delta, && \text{if}\ x =<\delta,\emptyset> \\
    &\alpha + \delta, && \text{if} \ x= <\delta,1>
  \end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}
Then show $h_\eta$ is an isomorphism between $<\alpha \sqcup \eta,\le_2>$ and $<\alpha + \eta,\underline\in_{\alpha+\eta}>$ where $\le_2$ is the usual order from $<\alpha^\#,\underline\in_{\alpha}^\#>$ to $<\eta^{\#\#},\underline\in_{\eta}^{\#\#}>$. Now let $h=\bigcup\{h_\eta|\eta \in \beta\}$ and show that $h$ is an isomorphism between $<\alpha \sqcup \beta,\le_3>$ and $<\alpha + \beta,\underline\in_{\alpha+\beta}>$ where $\le_3$ is the usual order from $<\alpha^\#,\underline\in_{\alpha}^\#>$ to $<\beta^{\#\#},\underline\in_{\beta}^{\#\#}>$. To show $h$ is an isomorphism, you will need to show, using their definitions, that it is a function, a bijection between the two sets and order embedding.
